# problems with DotNetOpenAuth OAuth2 Client for Google

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 application. 
Yesterday my users started to complain they cannot login using their Google accounts. After lots of googling I found this: [DotNetOpenAuth.GoogleOAuth2](https://github.com/mj1856/DotNetOpenAuth.GoogleOAuth2). I followed the instructions.

I created Client ID for web applications in Google console.

In AuthConfig.RegisterAuth() I have:

```
var client = new DotNetOpenAuth.GoogleOAuth2.GoogleOAuth2Client(googleClientID, googleClientSecret);
var extraData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient(client, "Google", extraData);
```

In AccountController, I have something like this:

```
public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    DotNetOpenAuth.GoogleOAuth2.GoogleOAuth2Client.RewriteRequest();
    AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));

    if (!result.IsSuccessful)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailure");
    }

    if (OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false))
            {
                // here I have some logic where is user sent when login was successfull
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                // If the current user is logged in add the new account
                OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, User.Identity.Name);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                // User is new, ask for their desired membership name
                string loginData = OAuthWebSecurity.SerializeProviderUserId(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId);
                // some logic
                return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new RegisterExternalLoginModel { UserName = username, ExternalLoginData = loginData, EncryptedEmail = encryptedEmail });
            }
        }
```

I have two problems:

1. Before the change, the `result.UserName` contained the users email. Now it contains name. But I need email. Except for this, registration works fine.
2. My biggest problem - existing users cannot log in using their google account.  The code goes to `"// User is new, ask for their desired membership name"` for them. The ProviderUserId I get now is different for the same email address.

Thanks a lot for any advice.

Comment: Please, anybody knows? I'm stuck and my users cannot login. I believe many people had to deal with this. Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you configure this library to pass additional parameters to the Google authorization service? If so, you should pass 'openid.realm=$your_app_openid2_realm' (if your app was configured for OpenID2 before, it most likely asserted a 'realm' value in its requests, you should use the same value).

In this case, you'll receive two identifiers from Google. The new one (which is compatible with profile URLs and overall more Google APIs) and the old one (returned as openid_id).

Comment: Yes, this library most likely can pass additional parameters, there is a Dictionary parameter extraData. I'm not sure what was used before, I just used the default security model for ASP.NET MVC 4 application. In Auth.Config there was only `OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterGoogleClient();`. I tried to search entire solution for "openid" and "realm" with no success.

Comment: Please does anybody know what ASP.NET MVC sends to google when using `OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterGoogleClient();`?